# How many dimensions I need to embed a graph?

Tags: topological-graph-theory, graph-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the max number of points in R^3, interconnected by generic curves?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9293/what-is-the-max-number-of-points-in-r3-interconnected-by-generic-curves)

Given a set of points connected by edges lying on an euclidean plane,
I'd like to find which is the smaller dimension of the euclidean space where the graph can lie without an overlapping of the edges. Is it a standard problem? Which mathematical tools I have to know to manage with this kind of problems?
I can obviously guess that I could always take $d=v-1$ where $v$ is the number of verticies
but I can't understand which is the smaller dimension.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Charles points out, you can always embed a graph in three dimensions. The interesting question is how complicated a **surface** one needs to embed a graph into. The number of handles one has to attach to a spehere in order for a graph to become embeddable is called the **genus** of the graph, see [graph embedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding) on Wikipedia, which offers other useful information.

Comment: +1 for suggesting related question with interesting results

Comment: Actually I was interested in: given a random graph, I'd like to know if this can be seen as the tessellation of a Manifold and which is its dimension, or something like this. I'm not really able to write the right question, but mine was not what I wanted to know. I guess that is something related to the genus. Could you give me some references? My ideas in this field are really fuzzy

Comment: I am not an expert in this topic, but a quick Google search suggests http://people.math.gatech.edu/~thomas/PAP/genus.pdf Perhaps you can have a look at this and ask another, more informed question on mathoverflow to get the experts' attention.

Answer (score 7):

Any graph embeds into $\mathbb{R}^3$.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding).

Comment: Or the previous question on this subject: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9293/what-is-the-max-number-of-points-in-r3-interconnected-by-generic-curves

Comment: Ahh, missed that question.  Anyways, what Qiaochu said.

Comment: ...assuming the cardinality of the vertex set is at most continuum.

Comment: True, though in context, random3f started out with a "Given a set of points connected by edges lying on an euclidean plane" which means it must be continuum or smaller.